# Comparing 2 attributes using the function "some"

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var e = require("./myApp.js");

var myServer = e.CreateServer(1337);

myServer.Register("/", "GET", function (req, res) { res.end("J") }); 
myServer.Register("/", "GET", function (req, res) { res.end("Ja") });

myServer.Start();
```

This is my "Wrapper":

```
module.exports = (function () {

function _createServer(port) {
    var routingTable = [];
    var port = port;
    var server = require('http').createServer();

    function _start() {
        server.listen(port);
        console.log("Server was started");
    };

    function RegisterRecord(url, method, fnc) {
        this.url = url;
        this.method = method;
        this.fnc = fnc;
    };

    function _register(newUrl, newMethod, newFnc) {

        if (_checkInput(newUrl, newMethod))
            console.log("Register failed! Record with same URL and Method already exist");
        else {

            routingTable.push(new RegisterRecord(newUrl, newMethod, newFnc));
            console.log("Register success!");                    
        }
    };

    function _checkInput(newUrl, newMethod) {
        return routingTable.some(function fnc(record) { record.url == newUrl && record.method == newMethod });  
    };

    return {
        Start: _start,
        Register: _register,
        ShutDown: _shutDown
    };
};

return { CreateServer: _createServer };

})();
```

So the most important functions are "_register" and "checkInput".

My aim is that the same URL and Method are only allowed on time in the array routingTable. So when I execute the programm, the Command Promp prints two times Register success. But "/" and "GET" should only be allowed one time.

How can I compare the URL and method so that they can be unique?

PS: The "Wrapper" is in the JS File "./MyApp.js"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
function _checkInput(newUrl, newMethod) {
    return routingTable
             .filter( function(el) {
               return el.url === newUrl && el.method === newMethod;
             })
             .length > 0;
};
```

**Upd.** Of course, you can use the `some` - you just forgot to return a value from it:

```
function _checkInput(newUrl, newMethod) {
    return routingTable
             .some( function(el) {
               // Need return
               return el.url === newUrl && el.method === newMethod;
             })
};
```

Comment: Thanks! but is it possible to use it with "some"? Or why does it not work with "some"?

Comment: @igodie Yes, of course, I'm sorry. I changed the answer.